# How to build a toilet under the sewer level?

Tags: basement, toilet

I have an old garage that I am recovering. Among other fixes I want to build a toilet. The issue here is that it's under the sewer level.

Is it still possible to build it? What do I need?

Comment: A sewage pump might work.

Comment: Don't fight gravity.

Comment: Hmmm.... toilet below sewer pipe. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

This type of [toilet pump combo](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Bathroom-Anywhere-Macerator-Pump-120-Volt-38724-0/202217665) allows you to lift all bathroom waste and water  up to appropriate level so it can be tied into your sewer system.

Here's a picture of how it sets up.

[image]

http://www.saniflo.com/products/index/show-product/lang/en/type/part/id/54

http://www.saniflo.com/?gclid=COLar4KYzckCFUcvgQod11kL4Q

Comment: There is something I don't understand about these. Do they pump up immediately to the sewer pipe or does it just grind and let it go to a tank where you pump it with a regular pump?

Comment: The holding tank you see behind the bowl  has a grind pump in it when water level rises to a certain point the pump kicks on and grinds as it pumps up the contents to the sewer Mine  in the basement works great lifting straight up 9.5 feet to sewer in first floor as you see the sink and shower both drain to the holding tank too

Comment: Ah, yes but what is mean is a larger tank. Like > 100Lts. I saw something recently, therefore my question. Would that be a possibility also? I saw one with a tank a pump like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-0-6-HP-Heavy-Duty-Cast-Iron-Sewage-Pump-ESE60W-HD/204667247 but I am not sure it serves the same purpose.

Comment: The pump runs directly to sewer or septic drains. No "larger tank" -- no advantage to having one that I can see.

Comment: How noisy is this when it kicks on?  Any louder than the tank filling?

Comment: @ nsn how far away is the nearest sewer  line you have access to?

Comment: @keshlam the ad vantage is not having to cut concrete floor and plumb beneath a slab

Comment: @JPhi1618 noise is better on the newer model http://saniflo.media-resources-ordp.com/2010/quiet-range-saniplus-macerator.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pam's suggestion, some more options:

- [incinerating toilet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incinerating_toilet)
- [composting toilet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composting_toilet)